# Playing midi sound through SoundPool, faced "Audio Fliger could not create track, status: -12" error

Tags: android, audio, midi, soundpool, ogg

I have a set of midi guitar sound, and I use soundpool to play as 12 strings like strumming. It plays well initially, and then the sound start missing. I check on the logcat and saw the below error messages

SoundPool   Error creating Audio Track
AudioTrack  Audio Fliger could not create track, status: -12

I search through stackoverlflow and found http://www.anddev.org/multimedia-problems-f28/soundpool-crashing-with-could-not-create-track-t17028.html#p52455 and [SoundPool: Error creating AudioTrack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599059/soundpool-error-creating-audiotrack). I wonder if I should get myself a tool that convert the midi sound to ogg format as one of the attempt of trying to solve this problem? Is playing midi through the soundpool not preferred compared to ogg?

Comment: I am not familiar with MIDI but check that it's the "right kind" of MIDI which is supported by Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: Thanks. The midi plays fine in Android. I'm just thinking if there's performance impact when playing midi vs playing ogg through Soundpool?

Comment: I'm not sure - my understanding is that midi is just an interface and the actual wave is played via samples. Perhaps there is some latency as it has to "get" these from the underlying audio system. Anyway, I have used ogg for my soundpool and it works well.

Comment: Thanks Ken. I'm refering to the midi sound file i.e. sound.mid.