# How to solve MediaPlayer error (100, 0) in nexus 5?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am getting the following error in nexus 5 when I play the video for 5-10 minutes.This error is not occurring always.It is working in nexus 9 and samsung duos.

> 10-08 09:03:14.033  14588-14599 W/AudioSystem﹕ AudioFlinger server died!
>   10-08 09:03:14.033  14588-14778 W/IMediaDeathNotifier﹕ media server died
>   10-08 09:03:14.043  14588-14778 E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (100, 0)
>   10-08 09:03:14.043  14588-14588 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
>   10-08 09:03:14.043  14588-14588 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41849ba8)
>   10-08 09:03:14.043  14588-14588 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: , PID: 14588
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: failure code: -32
>               at android.media.MediaPlayer.invoke(MediaPlayer.java:664)
>               at android.media.MediaPlayer.getInbandTrackInfo(MediaPlayer.java:1692)
>               at android.media.MediaPlayer.scanInternalSubtitleTracks(MediaPlayer.java:1851)
>               at android.media.MediaPlayer.access$600(MediaPlayer.java:529)
>               at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2198)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

It is working in nexus 5 emulator also.What might be the problem?and how to solve it?

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5653632/2546579) for this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5653099/2546579)

Answer (score 0):

Main reasons is memory issues, second could be mutlithread access on MediaPlayer. Do you have the code so we can elaborate more?